# Command line user interface instead of web-based interface for django?

Tags: python, django, web-services, rest

I have built a web platform with Django. Users with Staff status can log into Django-admin through their web browsers and add, remove or alter different objects, upload files, etc.

Now I want to build a command line tool to enable users to do these tasks via command line. The users need to authenticate in command line, and then use different commands to perform their target operation.

Think a command line *git* client to *github*.

Of course it's possible to authenticate and send form data using request or cURL. But is there any standard, better way of doing this? Is there any utility/library for this, maybe a Django/python one?

Comment: @jonrsharpe that's absolutely true, and irrelevant.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a '2-component' thing.

#### API

You will have to expose the desired functionality via an (RESTful) API.
Two common and very good libraries are [tastypie](http://tastypieapi.org/) and [Django REST Framework](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/).
They help you building APIs in a fast and flexible way - think about it as 'Django admin' for APIs.

#### Client

For request handling I would suggest to have a look at the [python-requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/) library.

**PS:** 
If you're interested - we did build a (quick, ugly, dirty & buggy) python client that interacts with our Django based service platform. You can [find it on GitHub](https://github.com/palmbeach-interactive/pbi-client)